# How to get the BindingExpression with the X:Bind syntax?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

If using the `{Binding Path}` syntax I can use `FrameworkElement.GetBindingExpression()` to access the binding expression and force it to update the source. As I sometimes want to do if using a TwoWay binding on a TextBox and need the binding to be updated on every keypress.

Is there a similar way to access the BindingExpression if using the new `{X:Bind Path}` syntax?

Or is there a different way to force the TwoWay binding to update on demand when using `X:Bind`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the view you can call Bindings.Update() does that work. there is no bindingexpression